# Aborting Files - Error in progress()

Tags: angularjs, ng-file-upload

When I abort my entire upload using the `$scope.cancelUpload()` function, everything cancels fine, except I get the following error:

> Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$scope.file_upload.statusLog[evt.config.data.index].percentage = progressPercentage')

I know that this error is being caused by me doing `$scope.file_upload.statusLog = []` in the last line of my cancel function, but I don't see any other way to clear the status percentages. They need to be cleared because I use this array to show percent uploaded when a file is being uploaded.

Does anyone know an alternative to fix this error?

```
$scope.file_upload = { file_array: [], statusLog: [], uploadArray: [] };

$scope.startUpload = function() {
    $scope.upload($scope.file_upload.file_array);
}


$scope.upload = function (files) {
    $scope.file_upload.statusLog = new Array(files.length);
    $scope.file_upload.uploadArray = new Array(files.length);

    if (files && files.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var file = files[i];
            if (!file.$error) {

                $scope.file_upload.statusLog[i] = { percentage: 0, complete: false };

                $scope.file_upload.uploadArray[i] = Upload.upload({
                    url: $rootScope.fileUploadURL, data: { index: i }
                }).progress(function (evt) {
                    /* WHERE THE ISSUE LIES */
                    var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
                    $scope.file_upload.statusLog[evt.config.data.index].percentage = progressPercentage;
                }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) { /* Stuff */ });
              }
            }
        }
    };


$scope.cancelUpload = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.file_upload.file_array.length; i++)
        $scope.file_upload.uploadArray[i].abort();

    $scope.file_upload.file_array = [], $scope.file_upload.statusLog = [], $scope.file_upload.uploadArray = [];
}
```

Comment: Just add checks for undefined in your code

Comment: could you elaborate @danial

Comment: `if ($scope.file_upload.statusLog[evt.config.data.index]) { $scope.file_upload.statusLog[evt.config.data.index].percentage = progressPercentage;}
`